# How to bold main nodes in jsTree with css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, jstree

I'am using https://www.jstree.com/ with asp.net mvc. I'am trying to bold the text with css in the main nodes, the one with arrows (see picture).

[image]

I have this code

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="jstree_demo_div" class="col-md-4">
        <ul id="tree">
            <li>
                <a href="#">@Model.CategoryName</a>
                @Html.Partial("_CategoryChildren", Model)
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="File-Upload-Category-Result" class="col-md-8"></div>
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model.Children)
{
    <ul>
        @if (item != null)
        {
            <li id="@item.CategoryID">
                <a href="@item.CategoryID" class="cat">@item.CategoryName</a>
                @if (item.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("_CategoryChildren", item)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

I have tried to put style almost every ware but it's not working, eg

```
 <span style="font-weight:900">@item.CategoryName</span>
```

Comment: you can use `pseudo-selectors` if you want.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: I can if you can show me your structure as browser generates your code and then explain exactly which nodes are you referring to be **bold**.
e.g. `ul > li:first-child > a { font-weight: bold }`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will do the trick:

```
.jstree-open > .jstree-anchor, .jstree-closed > .jstree-anchor {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: @vataka helped me instantly